# Discriminant analysis method to classify data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics

my aim is to classify the data into two sections- upper and lower- finding the mid line of the peaks.

I would like to apply machine learning methods- i.e. Discriminant analysis.

Could you let me know how to do that in MATLAB?

Comment: `findpeaks` has a host of options including number of peaks, threshold, peak distance, etc. I would first look into this before switching to another solution.

Comment: could you let me know which algorithm findpeaks function follows.

Comment: It's a simple detection of maxima using `diff`. Type `edit findpeaks` in the command line to reveal the code.

Comment: I already applied findpeaks and got result. but now I want to apply discriminant analysis methods in matlab. Do you know about it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are looking for is GMM (gaussian mixture model). With K=2 (number of mixtures) and dimension equal 1 this will be simple, fast method, which will give you a direct solution. Given components it is easy to analytically find a local minima (which is just a weighted average of means, with weights proportional to the std's).

Comment: Yes. Would you tell me how to do that in matlab @ lejlot